# Как жить с масштабированием в Windows и Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ос, scaling

Начну, пожалуй, с того, что у меня довольно скромный опыт взаимодействия с Linux, однако основы этой операционной системы (простите, ядра) мне в определенной степени известны. При этом основной ОС до недавнего времени была именно Windows.

В общем, не столько ради новых ощущений, сколько из-за некоторого дискомфорта, скорее, решил целиком и полностью переехать на Linux (Arch Linux, если точнее). Успел опробовать и Gnome, и KDE. В результате, конечно, столкнулся много с чем, но чего явно не ожидал увидеть ― проблему с масштабированием изображения.

Как известно, в Windows с этим все не очень радужно, но жить можно: встречаются размытый интерфейс, "шакальные" изображения и проблемы с позиционированием. Тогда как Linux, в свою очередь (по тем высказываниям, что до меня доходили), не имеет каких-то проблем с масштабированием. Но, как выяснилось, это, мягко говоря, не так: в KDE при масштабирование в 1.25 появились странные артефакты почти во всех приложениях, а в Gnome (помимо того, что эта функция считается **экспериментальной**) некоторые приложения стали размытыми и в общем система выглядит как-то странно (шрифты сщумают, что ли).

[image: Пример артефакта на KDE]

Соответственно, вопрос: как с этим всем справляться? Действительно ли Linux не сильно далеко ушел от Windows в этом аспекте?

Comment: открываете документацию на свой дистрибутив https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI и читаете. Но если линукс для Вас в новинку, попробуйте запустить ubuntu live / fedora и посмотреть, как оно там.

Comment: Не то чтобы совсем в новинку. Да, ранее ознакомился с этим разделом, но не увидел способов решения изложенных выше проблем (возможно, просмотрел, конечно, но это не точно).

Comment: со своего опыта - иногда шрифты выглядят вырвиглазно только потому, что они не масштабируются. И все. Но иногда помогает настройка хинтинга правильного.

Comment: В первую очередь беспокоит размытость интерфейса в сторонних приложениях (Gnome). Со шрифтами, возможно, все в порядке; непривычно, скорее.

Comment: Размытость из-за шрифтов. Я "пошаманил" (используя найденные в интернете советы)  в свое время и  с тех пор (у меня одна Mint/Cinnamon, другая Xubuntu/Xfce) вроде все хорошо. Помню ставил какой-то дополнительный пакет с шрифтами и что-то настраивал, но к сожалению, что именносейчас не вспомню. Думаю, через пару дней поиска в гугле и экспериментов у вас тоже получится.

Comment: @avp, наверное рендеринг меняли с помощью  freetype.